# Read Data from Firebase to Display in My UIPickerView

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uipickerview

**My database structure**

[image: My database structure]

I am having a problem to display data list from firebase to my UIPickerView.

I want to set it as options 
like the data list in firebase should be my UIPickerview options:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import Firebase

var vehicalList = [String]()


class CausticSodaEntryVC: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, 
UIPickerViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var causticVehical: UIPickerView!

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
{
    return vehicalList.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, 
forComponent component: Int) -> String?
{
    return vehicalList[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent 
component: Int) -> Int
{
    return vehicalList.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, 
inComponent component: Int)
{
    print(" ")
}
```

Comment: whats the issue ?

Comment: where are you appending data to vehicalList ?

Comment: var vehicalList = [String:Any]() then after fecthing the node from firebase append it vehicalList

Comment: @iOSGeek the issue is only vehicle numbers should display in pickerView list

Comment: @VaibhavParmar i am appending data of Vehicle from firebase to vehicleList

Comment: is it like data is Appended but picker doesn't show any nam e?

Comment: Can you more clearly describe what your expected result is? Also, a lot of what you do with Firebase is determined by how to read the data - as it is only the vehicleList array is being shown in the code but we don't know what's in the array i.e. I get it's a string, but a string of what?

Comment: @Jay hello sir, I want the array of vehicle from firebase to display in my pickerView as a string

Comment: @iOSGeek, yes sir, the array of vehicle list from firebase is not appearing in my pickerView as a string

Comment: What is an *array of vehicle*? Do you mean MH09CT230, mh12hg123, mh13bs2345? Also, what difficulty are you having with reading that data? Those are the child node keys so as you iterate over your snapshot that would be snapshot.key for each node. Can you post your Firebase code so we can see how your Firebase data is being read? (.childAdded? .value?) Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Seems like you picker is appearing before data is fetched from firebase , as it run async mode , so show picker only when array count is greater than 0 , put a check on it